# Indonesian Passport transiting Seoul to LA

Tags: visas, indonesian-citizens

I am holding an Indonesian passport, studying in the United States. So, I am holding a US visa. I am going to transit in Seoul for 23 hours layover from Los Angeles to Indonesia.

Do I need a visa to enter Seoul for 23 hours?

Answer (score 1):

No. You are eligible to get a 30 day visa exemption for transit.

> Non visa-exempt nationals who are in transit through South Korea are
>   visa-exempt for 30 days, provided they hold a physical visa or a
>   residence permit issued by the following countries, and meet one of
>   the routing requirements:
>
> - They are directly arriving in South Korea from one of these countries and going to a third country, or directly leaving South Korea to one of these countries after arriving from a third country;
>     or,
> - They are arriving in South Korea from one of these countries and have transited in a fourth country for less than 72 hours before entering South Korea, and continuing to a third country; or,
> - They are leaving South Korea after arriving from a third country to one of these countries and will be transiting in a fourth country for less than 72 hours.
>
> **Eligible Visas**
>
> - Australia
> - Canada
> - New Zealand
> - **United States**

Alternatively, you can participate in an organized tour for roughly 10$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_South_Korea#Transit

Comment: Your first sentence says "yes you need a visa" and then your quote says "no you're visa exempt for 30 days". Which is it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Edited the answer.